# graphql-spring-boot-starter Application with only websockets

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, graphql

I am building a graphql application with *spring-boot-starter-webflux 2.5.6* and *com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:12.0.0*.
At this point the application is running fine since *com.graphql-java-kickstart* is easy to start with.
With http-Requests I can call Queries and run Mutations and I am even able to create and get updates via Subscriptions over websockets.

But for my application Queries and Mutations also have to run via websocket.

It seems that in com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter you can only configure a subscription endpoint as websocket.
Adding an additional websocket via 'extends Endpoint' and '@ServerEndpoint' did nothing at all.

I also tried to add my own HandlerMapping:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(
            ((SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) webSocketHandlerMapping).getUrlMap());
    
    map.put("/mysocket", myWebSocketHandler);
    //map.put("/graphql", myWebSocketHandler);

    ((SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) webSocketHandlerMapping).setUrlMap(map);
    ((SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) webSocketHandlerMapping).initApplicationContext();

}
```

This seems to work with the /mysocket Topic but how do I enable it for /graphql, it seems like there is already a handler listening on:

`WARN 12168 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] notprivacysafe.graphql.GraphQL           : Query failed to parse : ''`

And how to connect the websocket with my GraphQLMutationResolvers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My entry point to a solution for this problem was to create a `RestController` and connect the `ServerWebExchange` to a `WebSocketHandler` in the `WebSocketService` like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WebSocketController
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketController.class);

    private final GraphQLObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final GraphQLInvoker graphQLInvoker;

    private final GraphQLSpringInvocationInputFactory invocationInputFactory;

    private final WebSocketService service;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketController(GraphQLObjectMapper objectMapper, GraphQLInvoker graphQLInvoker,
            GraphQLSpringInvocationInputFactory invocationInputFactory, WebSocketService service)
    {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.graphQLInvoker = graphQLInvoker;
        this.invocationInputFactory = invocationInputFactory;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("${graphql.websocket.path:graphql-ws}")
    public Mono<Void> getMono(ServerWebExchange exchange)
    {
        logger.debug("New connection via GET");
        return service.handleRequest(exchange,
                new GraphQLWebsocketMessageConsumer(exchange, objectMapper, graphQLInvoker, invocationInputFactory));
    }

    @PostMapping("${graphql.websocket.path:graphql-ws}")
    public Mono<Void> postMono(ServerWebExchange exchange)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

In this prototype state the `WebSocketHandler` is also implementing the `Consumer` which is called to handle each `WebSocketMessage`:

```
public class GraphQLWebsocketMessageConsumer implements Consumer<String>, WebSocketHandler
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GraphQLWebsocketMessageConsumer.class);

    private final ServerWebExchange swe;

    private final GraphQLObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final GraphQLInvoker graphQLInvoker;

    private final GraphQLSpringInvocationInputFactory invocationInputFactory;

    private final Sinks.Many<String> publisher;

    public GraphQLWebsocketMessageConsumer(ServerWebExchange swe, GraphQLObjectMapper objectMapper,
            GraphQLInvoker graphQLInvoker, GraphQLSpringInvocationInputFactory invocationInputFactory)
    {
        ...
        publisher = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession)
    {
        Mono<Void> input = webSocketSession.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText).doOnNext(this).then();
        Mono<Void> sender = webSocketSession.send(publisher.asFlux().map(webSocketSession::textMessage));
        return Mono.zip(input, sender).then();
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String body)
    {
        try
        {
            String query = extractQuery(body);
            if(query == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            GraphQLRequest request = objectMapper.readGraphQLRequest(query);
            GraphQLSingleInvocationInput invocationInput = invocationInputFactory.create(request, swe);
            Mono<ExecutionResult> executionResult = Mono.fromCompletionStage(graphQLInvoker.executeAsync(invocationInput));
            Mono<String> jsonResult = executionResult.map(objectMapper::serializeResultAsJson);
            jsonResult.subscribe(publisher::tryEmitNext);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private String extractQuery(final String query) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) objectMapper.getJacksonMapper().readValue(query, Map.class);
        ...
        return queryPart;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getSubProtocols()
    {
        logger.debug("getSubProtocols called");
        return Collections.singletonList("graphql-ws");
    }

}
```

This solution does not yet touch security aspects like authentication or session handling.